# Spring Data Elasticsearch mapping id named field inside _source

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to map documents from ElasticSearch into java objects using Spring Data Elastic (4.0.2). My problem is the following: I have two id fields one is the _id for the document itself, and one id inside _source.

```
@Document(indexName = "logger-logs-*", createIndex = false)
public class LogMessage {

    @Id
    private String _id;

    @Field(name = "id")
    private int messageId;
}

{
    "_index" : "logger-logs-2020-03-01",
    "_type" : "logger-logs",
    "_id" : "xyz8iUCJdBd2Vs=",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "timestamp" : 1583103045441,
      "level" : "info",
      "levelNumber" : 3,
      "id" : 10891
    }
  }
```

If I put @Id on one and @Field(name = "id") on the other as shown in the example above, I get an exception which states that I can't have two Id fields:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Attempt to add property private int messageId but already have property private java.lang.String _id registered as id. Check your mapping configuration!
```

I was also trying with @Field(name = "_source.id") but it was not working neither:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a Map.
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use *messageId* for this field? The problem is that in Spring Data Elasticsearch, a property is considered to the id property of the entity if one of the following is true:

- it is annotated with `@Id`
- it is named *id*
- it is named *document*

We will deprecate the behaviour of using the name of the property in 4.1 and remove it earliest in 4.2.

So currently not using *id* for this property would be the way to go.

Comment: We are considering renaming the field, but not sure yet if it's possible. What behaviour/feature is going to be deprecated exactly, could you explain it a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: the feature that naming a property _id_ or _document_ makes this the id-property. When this is removed, only the `@Id` annotation is taken into account, and then can have a field named _id_ without problems